# firebase - query inner object

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data in firebase:

```
"posts": {
  "ts-functions": {
    "metrics": {
      "views" : 100,
      "likes" : 251000,
      "shares": 1200,
    },
    "title" : "Why you should use TypeScript for writing Cloud Functions",
    "author": "Doug",
  },
  "android-arch-3": {
    "metrics": {
      "views" : 100,
      "likes" : 117000,
      "shares": 144,
    },
    "title" : "Using Android Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database (Part 3)",
    "author": "Doug",
  }
},
```

Is it posible make a query like this?

```
mDatabase.child("posts").child(ANYTHING).child("metrics").equalTo(100).addValueEventListener;
```

I would like to get only the metrics objects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for citing a couple of my blogs. I understand you probably pulled this from the Firebase docs, but hey.  :-)

Unfortunately, there are no wildcards in Realtime Database queries. Your query must begin at a fully specified location in the database.

And you can't extract a specific child from a list of children, ignoring all the other adjacent children. When you read a location in the database, you necessarily read all children at that location.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Doug's answer what i like to do is keep a class with all of the `DatabaseReference` as constants with parameters.

In this way i don't have to create a reference inside an `Activity` that's pretty obvious.

```
private static DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

public static DatabaseReference post(String titleKey) {
       return root.child(titleKey);
}

public static DatabaseReference metrics(String titleKey) {
       return post(titleKey).child("metrics");
}
```